# Getting ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm No JDK found

Tags: java, python, pycharm

I am trying to use PyCharm 4.0.3 (community version) with Red Hat 6.3. I downloaded Linux version from PyCharm website and extracted it on my Linux machine. When I ran PyCharm it initially gave me below error

```
ERROR: Cannot start PyCharm
No JDK found. Please validate either PYCHARM_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

Then I added below two lines in my `~/.cshrc` (I am using tcsh)

```sh
setenv JAVA_HOME /tools/jre1.6.0
setenv PATH ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
```

I verified that Java location is correct but now when I run PyCharm  it doesn't do anything and I get the control back on command prompt.

Comment: First, does `java -version` work? Second, why did you pick an EOL version of Java?

Comment: Here is the output of java -version   java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode).

Comment: jdk1.5.0@        jre1.5.0@        jre1.5.0_06.off/ jre1.6.0_21/     
jdk1.5.0_06/     jre1.5.0_06/     jre1.6.0@   There are all java/JDK versions I have available on my system

Comment: Just making sure: this is not a server, it has GUI (X display manager), right?

Comment: Seems unlikely he'd be running pycharm, which is an IDE, on a headless server.

Just to clarify: do you have OpenJDK 1.6, or Sun Java 1.6. Because it looks like the latter isn't supported (OpenJDK has to be 1.7+).

Answer (score 4):

For running PyCharm you need to install Oracle Java. Install Oracle Java with the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After successful execution of above commands you can run `pycharm.sh` file in the bin folder.

Comment: this ppa doesn't exist anymore

Comment: ppa exists now. This solution worked for me (jul-2017)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem
To solve this problem
First you need to install java jdk 1.8

Below link java sdk 32 bit version
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-i586.tar.gz

For 64 bit 
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz